# Punk rock song, lyrics: "mix between a wolf and a lamb"

Tags: identify-this-song, lyrics, rock, punk

I heard this song at a shopping mall the other day,I can hardly remember the lyrics, it was something like a punk rock song , that's all I remember :

"I'm like a mix between a wolf and a lamb , I stall myself in fall and spring ..."

I have searched for keywords,but had no luck .
Can anyone please identify the song ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's *Balanced Boy* by Millencolin, which you can find [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VD0QKC78wqU).